# Jackson Json: encode multiple lists of objects

Tags: list, jackson, json, multiple-tables

I have a few lists of objects in Java that I'd like to have encoded in json using Jackson 2.2.2 together:

```
List<Department> departments = this.departmentService.listAll();
List<Role> roles = this.roleService.listAll();
```

I'd love to have a resulting json looking like this:

```
[
    "departments": [
                    {
                     "departmentId": 1,
                     "otherKey" : otherValue
                    },
                    { ... }
                   ],
    "roles": [
              {
               "roleId": 1,
               "otherKey" : otherValue
              }
             ]
]
```

I'm not sure this Json is perfect but I guess you get the idea.
**Is there a way to do this?**

Thank you!

Comment: Just use an another wrapper (POJO with two properties, or a java.util.map).

Comment: Gonna try with a new pojo :) thanks

Comment: That worked with a new POJO wrapper and it outputs what I excepted. Thank you. Post this as an answer if you want to be rewarded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.put("departments", departments);
map.put("roles", roles);
```

Then you can serialize the map into json

Comment: I wish you had answered before I created a ton of POJO-wrappers... :p

Comment: Sometimes map is much flexible than POJO :)